# What's the relationship between the song "Jeepers Creepers" and the movie title?

Tags: title, jeepers-creepers

In [*Jeepers Creepers*](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0263488/), there is a scene in which Fatty and a girl are in a diner, they get a call from a woman, and she plays [a song](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d0lgswGOgrs).

From [Fanton media](http://jeeperscreepers.wikia.com/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_(film)):

> While waiting for the cops to arrive, they are phoned by a local psychic, Jezelle Gay Hartman, who warns them about the danger they face. **She plays them the song "Jeepers Creepers" on the phone**, and tells them that when they hear that song, they will be in extreme danger.

What connection does the creature have with this song? And why would they choose the name "Jeepers Creepers" as the movie title?

Is the creature only attacking victims who heard this song? Based on *Jeepers Creepers 2*, this seems to be wrong. Did I miss something?

Comment: It's probably the auto correct version of Darry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She just knew, through her psychic powers (I don't think it was specified how her powers works), that "they'll be in extreme danger, when they hear that song", so she warned them.

She used the song playing because she didn't know any other specifics about the time this will happen.

So, she was just using a unique marker from her vision (e g "I don't know when, but it's when you see this street sign..."). The creature don't know or care about the song.

Also,

> Jeepers kreepers, where'd you get those eyes...... how'd they get so lit up...... how'd they get this size

Those lyrics fit the events of the movie, "A creature fascinated by someone's eyes and gets them.

And the term itself is an expression for surprise or shock, so it makes a fitting name for the movie.

Comment: Yeah, I did mentioned that, "where'd you get those eyes..." & "A creature fascinated by someone's eyes and gets them"

Answer (score 2):

The word peepers is an informal term meaning "eyes". And the main lyric of the song Jeepers Creepers is:

```
Jeepers creepers, where'd you get those peepers?
Jeepers creepers, where'd you get those eyes?
```

Given that the body-part stealing creature

> covets the eyes of the poor young man he is pursuing

it is reasonable to suspect that this song amuses the creature in some way, and might explain why it chooses to listen to this song while it is busy at work.